# extracting a tuple out of a list of tuples using haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I have this derived data type AcInfo which consists of the following  user created data types 
`[(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)]`
(all are strings except Amnt which is an Int) what i want is to get a tuple out of the following list by checking the AcNo.

I made the declaration and a bit further, but I am finding it hard to figure out what to do next.  The declaration:

```
accountDetails :: AcInfo -> AcNo -> [Name, City, Amnt]
accountDetails dbase number
```

Will the use of list comprehension be useful? Furthermore, what would be a good way of going for a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `AcNo -> [(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)] -> (AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)` to extract a the tuple that matches the `AcNo`?

Comment: this is my type decelerations
type AcNo = String;
type Name = String;
type City = String;
type Amnt = Int;

type AcInfo = [(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)]

Comment: When you have a tuple with more than 2 elements, you should probably create a custom data type to represent that grouping of information. `data AcRecord = AcRecord { acNo, name, city :: String, amnt :: Int }`. If you are not yet accustomed, familiarize yourself with [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with list comprehensions pretty easily:

```
locateAcct :: AcNo -> [(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)] -> (AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)
locateAcct account db = head [ tup | tup@(ac, _, _, _) <- db, ac == account ]
```

Of course, by using `head`, we open ourselves up to the possibility of a failed match. Perhaps a better approach would be to use something like the [safe library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe)'s version of headMay, which returns Nothing if the list is empty:

```
locateAcct :: AcNo -> [(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)] -> Maybe (AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)
locateAcct account db = headMay [ tup | tup@(ac, _, _, _) <- db, ac == account ]
```

Now if that account doesn't exist, you get Nothing instead of a pattern match failure.

Comment: `headMay` is also available in the standard libraries as `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`.

Answer (score 1):

`find ((==) target . fst4)` : http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/find_f.html

where `fst4` is a version of `fst` that takes a 4-tuple.  Not sure if it is in a library, but it is easy to write.